# Reformatting String in Python

Tags: python

I am looking for some help on the following reformatting problem.

I have 3 random characters that appear joined in my data set. I need to separate the first character with a space from the other two, then insert a '/' between remaining two. i.e.

random_char = '713'
expected_result = '7 1/3'

Comment: How should I understand "three random characters" Do you know beforehand which three you are looking for, in which context they have to stand or that it should be three numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply separate string into characters and form as you want to use them. in your case it can be formed as:

```
a = '732'
print(a[0] + ' ' + a[1] + '/' + a[2])
```

output will be `7 3/2`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your string is always exactly three characters, here is one solution:

```
random_char = '713'
result = '{} {}/{}'.format(*random_char)

print(result)
>>> '7 1/3'
```

The `{}` are placeholders, and the `*random_char` 'unpacks' the characters of your original string into the three placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

```
random_char = '713'

# using unary '*' as the unpack operator
print('{} {}/{}'.format(*random_char))

# is here equivalent to
print('{} {}/{}'.format(random_char[0], random_char[1], random_char[2]))
```